# Securely erase SSDs (The whole SSD)

Tags: ssd

I want to sell my SSD to my friend, it's a 256GB, I have personal stuff on this SSD, so I want to make sure that it will become extremely hard or *at least* hard to recover the data back. **Erasing the whole SSD, as if it were new.**

The other questions similar to this one are *over-mentioning* that:

1. erasing one partition is useless.
2. The commands `cat`, `dd`, `shred` are useless.

I read that erasing the SSD is only useful when erasing the whole disk and not only one partition.
So I'm asking to make sure if this information is correct and to know how to do it.

So I thought it would be better to create a new thread here for me and for those people who aren't concerned about data losing anything because they only want to get rid of their SSDs in return for money instead of throwing them in the garbage.

Comment: There's many search results for "secure erase SSD in linux" - and yes, if you think your friend is going to try and recover your personal "stuff" (nudge nudge wink wink) - you'll want to secure erase the SSD

Comment: Is encrypting the complete SSD an option?

Comment: I don't know from memory what I used years ago, maybe [this tool](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/). Good luck.

Comment: For ATA (SSD or not), have a look there (hardware/firmware feature-dependent): https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/42266/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-empty-a-ssd

Comment: Smack it with a hammer.

Comment: @A.B Worth noting, high end SSDs that implement Secure Erase do not "erase" the SSD, but rather resets the crypto key in the controller. This is worth considering when Eve has resources above state actor level, such as a Kardashev Type 5 civ.

Comment: You need to also consider that SSD are overprovisioned. That means that a 100 GB driver actually has 110 GB where extra copies of data are stored. Your OS tools won't ever be able to access the overpartitioned sectors, and that data will remain there. Maybe some manufacturer tools can get there, though, but your standard tools can't.

Comment: @Aron indeed, I knew that.

Comment: oh my god, what happened. I forgot all about this question and now it has 2k views, looks like I wasn't the only one suffering here ️

Answer (score 21):

Useless depends on context. shred can actually be rather useless - when trying to shred a single file, while other copies of the file still exist [every time you click Save, it's another copy] - but there's also the hand sanitizer definition of useless: it kills 99.9% so in practice, it's not useless at all, but people worry about the 0.01% anyway.

For many SSDs, a simple `blkdiscard` will cause that data to be gone and never to be seen again.

```
blkdiscard -v /dev/deleteyourssd
# verification:
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
cmp /dev/zero /dev/deleteyourssd
# expected result: EOF on /dev/deleteyourssd
```

If that's not good enough for you, you can use `dd` or `shred` to do a random data wipe:

```
dd bs=1M status=progress if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/deleteyourssd
# or
shred -v -n 1 /dev/deleteyourssd
```

For verification, the random data wipe needs to be done by encrypting zeroes:

```
cryptsetup open --type plain --cipher aes-xts-plain64 /dev/deleteyourssd cryptyourssd
# Three unicorns went into a bar and got stuck in the door frame
badblocks -b 4096 -t 0 -s -w -v /dev/mapper/cryptyourssd
```

You can also run another verification pass after power cycling (for the encryption method it works only if you re-use the same passphrase):

```
cmp /dev/zero /dev/mapper/cryptyourssd
# expected result: EOF on /dev/mapper/cryptyourssd
```

Getting data back — after discarding/overwriting **and** verifying that everything's gone — would require a bit of a miracle and involves corner cases that most users don't really need to concern themselves with.

But if that's still not good enough for you, you can use Secure Erase if the SSD manufacturer provides it for your SSD model, this is described in detail in the ArchLinux wiki:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing

Just don't mess it up by setting complex ATA password and then locking yourself out, effectively bricking the device. Keep it simple.

---

Usually with SSDs, it's already quite impossible to restore any data simply after reinstalling Linux, since most flavors `mkfs` also discard the entire space first thing:

```
mke2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem [...]
```

In this fashion it's indeed quite useless to erase SSDs yourself, since everything already does that for you without asking, anyway.

And even if that didn't happen, almost every distro sets up `fstrim` to wipe all free space regularly. Data recovery is a lot less successful on SSDs than on HDDs where you actually have to go out of your way to overwrite free space.

SSDs are so good at discarding all your data in an eyeblink, you should really worry more about losing the data you still need (make backups and backups of your backups), than worry about being unable to erase it.

Comment: In a lab environment it's probably possible to restore the contents of an SSD which has only seen blkdiscard since this command does not overwrite memory cells.

Comment: Most SSD should actually erase their discarded memory cells, as doing so gives a performance benefit, vs. zero benefits in keeping old data around. But yes, blkdiscard/fstrim as well as Secure Erase, depend on implementation details. If you don't trust the hardware then writing random data **and** verifying its there, is already the best you can do.

Comment: the blkdiscard command takes a millisecond to complete - I don't think firmware actually wipes the blocks before they are being reused.

Comment: It's a background task (and it just doesn't take all that long)... you can check that the SSD no longer returns the data, as for what happens internally it's a black box. Wiping with random data **and** verifying is much stronger as it gives you formal proof that at least *nominal capacity* worth of data has been overwritten. As for what is left even then, yes well that's the 0.01% discussion, and perhaps not too relevant for the "sell it to a friend" use case.

Comment: 100 % - 99.9 % = 0.1 %

Answer (score 11):

```
blkdiscard -v -f /dev/nvme0n1 (or /dev/sdX)
```

Will make your data effectively vanish without any realistic possibility of restoring it.

If you're paranoid, do this:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/nvme0n1
```

followed by `blkdiscard`.

Comment: `-f` (force) seems dangerous - I'd leave that out by default and only add it if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The *only* way to securely erase a NAND Flash drive is to ask the drive controller to do it for you. Host base utilities that use writes will not work. If it's a NVMe drive look up the [nvme format command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=devices-secure-data-deletion-nvme-drive)