# How to calculate the checksum while writing random data to a disk?

Tags: hard-disk, dd, hashsum

I have a disk which is perhaps broken. I want to write random data to the disk and later verify the md5 checksum.

I write to the disk like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress
```

How to create the md5 checksum while writing to the disk at the same time? I want to see the md5 checksum of the written random data when dd finishes. Also I want to see the progress while writing to the disk.

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-output-of-one-program-into-two-other-programs) post and I created this command:

```
pv /dev/urandom >(md5sum) > /dev/sdXXX
```

The problem is it fills up my whole RAM. I got 32GB RAM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to pipe the output of one program into two other programs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-output-of-one-program-into-two-other-programs)

Comment: It's possible (for example using tee). If you're open to alternatives, you can also use cryptsetup instead, example 
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681556/30851

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have read it and I got a command now. But the problem is it fills up my whole RAM and I got 32GB. So I clicked "no" when I was asked if this post solves my problem. The command I got is: pv /dev/urandom >(md5sum) > /dev/sdXXX

Comment: Instead of writing random data could you use `badblocks -w -s` instead? It does a write to each block followed by a read and a compare and will show progress of the scan.

Comment: @doneal24 I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I wrote this up as an answer to the problem even if it doesn't answer the question asked. Consider accepting the answer if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write your own solution you can use a standard scan utility.

```
badblocks -w -s /dev/sda
```

will scan the entire disk, writing patterns to each individual block then reading the block back and comparing the results. Progress is displayed during the scan. You can also specify a number of passes if the default single pass doesn't seem like enough.