How to truly securely erase a nvme disk?
I was trying to securely erase my disk, and realized this is a much more difficult task than I expected, and even the first link of stackexchange is not really updated, and quite dangerous indeed
Is shred bad for erasing SSDs?
I was going to use shred from live linux usb, but it appears it is not safe for SSD (and nvme?) so I should used blkdiscard -s but it says my device is not supported
blkdiscard: /dev/nvme0n1: BLKSECDISCARD ioctl failed: Operation not supported

The other question is quite dangerous because it says they are not worried with advanced data recovery methods, but this is not my case, and the first result in google shouldn't make people do dangerous things.
I also discovered this ATA Secure Erase from the linux kernel but even they say this is outdated
I am looking for what is truly the most secure method for erasing data in a device, like if your life depends on it, short of burning the disk to ashes or something.
So based on my research what we should do is
blkdiscard -s if supported, also blkdiscard -v and then also just to be sure shred -v
Tear of the hardware is not a concern at all, but can we even trust that software solutions can be 100% safe those days?

If your life depends on it, physically shredding the drive is the most secure way of "erasing" it. If your life depended on it, you would not let the drive remain in a computer and would want it not to be usable in a computer ever again.

regardless of the method, add a verification step, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681556/30851

As is often the case, there is lots of info on
archlinux
including a special page on clearing.

You want to use nvme tools, nvme-cli. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310338/how-to-secure-erase-a-nvme-ssd/1310876#1310876 & see nvme section: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives/Memory_cell_clearing

AFAIK the BLKSECDISCARD ioctl has never been associated to any command in ATA/ACS or NVMe standards. (Probably not any in SCSI too.) IIRC it originates from a command that is implemented in some (e)MMC controllers/drives.

As for BLKDISCARD, all it does is that it tells the drive that a range (could be the whole drive) of logical blocks is not considered "used" (like contains data that you want to retain) anymore. Often with recent drives, especially NVMe ones AFAIK, the consequence is that the logical blocks would be unmapped from actual storage and "read zero", but the "read zero" part isn't exactly guaranteed. (But well I have to admit that I never bothered to read the NVMe spec to see if it mandates anything with that respect.) Besides, "read zero" covers only "normal" reads.


I also discovered this ATA Secure Erase from the linux kernel but even they say this is outdated

The website as a whole is outdated (hence its address being archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/), but the ATA Secure Erase method is not. However, as the name suggests, it is for ATA devices (i.e. SATA HDDs/SSDs) – whereas your NVMe device is not an ATA device, so although it has an equivalent, it needs to be managed using NVMe tools.
The NVMe equivalent would be the nvme sanitize /dev/xxx command.

I am looking for what is truly the most secure method for erasing data in a device, like if your life depends on it, short of burning the disk to ashes or something.

Physical destruction is a widely accepted method, although you do need to make sure that the flash storage chips themselves are destroyed – not necessarily turned into ashes but at least cut in half or something.
(I believe that if your assumed attacker had the capability and willingness to recover useful data out of a chip with a large hole in it – one that you did not encrypt before putting such critical data on it – then you'd also be having bigger problems that further destruction of the SSD wouldn't really solve...)

In some sense ATA Secure Erase is "outdated", given that new ACS standards / ATA drives has their own Sanitize Device feature set as well that doesn't require silly procedure like having to set a drive password before the erasure (that would be unset right away after the erasure). But yeah AFAIK it isn't removed from or declared obsoleted in new ACS standards. And some NVMe drives even implement the ATA Security feature set (probably for "backward compatiblity" that allows a "simple drive lock" to be set through some UEFI firmware, namely AMI ones).

Encrypt the drive with an 'impossible' password (maybe just slap the keyboard several times). Repeat with a different, equally-unmemorable password, possibly several times.
LUKS is a widely-available encryption tool for Linux. There are many guides available.
Afterwards, reformat and reuse, or destroy.

The ATA security set (which Secure Erase is a part of) is usually locked-out by the BIOS on boot, because it was intended that the BIOS use it to manage a disk password, sorta like an insecure version of TCG Opal that doesn't encrypt anything.  It's also, of course, an ATA feature not NVME. The feature set you want at run time is called "Sanitize".  There's at least two types of sanitize operation:
On any SSD or similar with always-on media encryption there's the crypto-scramble sanitize operation.  This simply makes all data inaccessible by causing the disk to forget and re-set the media encryption key. SSDs often have this encryption running at all times just to keep zeros on disk from forming large groupings of the same charge for physical reasons. This could also be done by enabling TCG Opal disk encryption and then reverting it without the revertnoerase option.
SSDs also have to option to perform a block-erase sanitize which will wipe all flash as quickly as possible.  This is more the operation you were thinking of.

The so-to-speak "lock out" is more or less part of the feature set, assuming you mean drives connected directly (like to SATA ports instead of USB bridge) would often get into the "frozen" state. And somehow a S3(-only) suspend-resume cycle seem to have become sort of a "de facto standard" to get the drive "unfrozen". (Actually such "lock out" has at least been observed in some lenovo laptops for NVMe drives/commands, with suspend-resume also being the way to unfreeze. I don't remember if it was the sanitize command or the format command though; or maybe both.)

To be precise, block erase sanitize (or "read zero" TRIM) only guarantees that the "logical blocks" are being unmapped from the actual flash storage. It doesn't really make sure the latter is "wiped", at the very least not "synchronously" before the command returns. (And tbh, even crypto scramble sanitization is still just a "black box" -- you can only "trust" that it does what you think it does behind the scene)

@TomYan If they're implemented correctly it should work as desired, and more reliably than an overwrite which can't touch the overprovisioned area.  But yes, in my experience sanitize-block-erase only triggers a background operation.  But if you give it a few minutes you can hexdump a full disk of zeros.

Well I really meant is, hexdump a full disk of zeros doesn't mean that the memory behind the scene are wiped. It just means that none of the logical blocks are mapped to any storage. (But then after they are unmapped, the drive controller would probably start "garbage collection" on at least some of of the memory. It's just that's like a complete "black-box realm" that might highly differ among controllers. We can't really tell how much would actually get wiped unless we go inspect the memory with "forensic method", like NOT via the controller / LBA read / FTL).

I actually forgot the sanitize command itself is also technically "asynchronous", that you can check whether "the job" has completed by checking a "log" or something. (Although that part normally just takes a blink anyway.) In the NVMe case you can even check whether any write has been performed since the last sanitize, IIRC.

from what you've written, and haven't mentioned...

an nvme disk doesn't really mean much; nvme is just the connection method to the pci bus, just like if you said sata disk or ata disk or pata ribbon cable disk from the 80's.
you need to mention the disk controller specifically, and preferably the make/model of the drive, and what functionality the disk controller and firmware supports in regards to secure erasing.
Enterprise class SED's (self-encrypting disks) when used in enterprise-class servers where the bios/uefi and hardware-raid card supports it, there's a specific option for changing the AES encryption key of the SED where with one mouse click "erases" the disk... technically the encryption key is changed so unless you can break that specific encryption algorithm the data left on the SED in not decryptable.
On the other end of the spectrum is old conventional hard disk drives (HDD's) with the spinning platters whose controllers and firmware were written long before encryption was a thing then on these something like DBAN which overwrites the entire platter(s) multiple times is the only way to "erase" that disk.
Mainstream today with typical consumer grade SSD, such as samsung or intel, a simple repartition and a [gpt] relabel of the whole ssd followed by causing TRIM to happen effectively erases it... if you believe the firmware of the SSD and the controller actually performs TRIM.  If you buy some cheap chinese knockoff sdd with who knows what controller firmware, how much would you bet it actually performs everything the way it's supposed to.
for the basic SSD with credible controller firmware, you do not need all the fancy programs like dban or nwipe or shred to actually write to the disk.  The TRIM when done on clean correct empty file system wipes the disk;  you need to read the technical description of TRIM to understand why that is the case.  Don't believe me - properly perform a TRIM on an SSD then send it to some data recovery place and see what they say, or call and ask them.
and then to truly erase the only real method is complete physical destruction, especially with the old platter HHD's.  "Truly" really depends on the competency and knowledge of the operator trying to erase the given disk.  Ironically, when you don't want to have done that you will have, and when you want to truly erase the [entire] disk there's possibility it would not have been.
no, you cannot trust the software solutions to be 100% these days.  you would be naive if you did, in the exception of the very rare case you have the source code, AND can understand it, and compile it to executable yourself.


and, haven't played this option in a long time, download a disk recovery tool many will give you 1 or 2 tries for free with less than full functionality, test it's recovery on a disk that you've performed some erase scheme on,  if it picks out any 1 file/folder name you recognize then the disk was not sanitized.  I've done this, long time ago, on HDD's, quite remarkable how a complete re-partition that shows up as a blank file system can have intact files recovered from.  For starters simply try this on an SSD after TRIM has been performed.
